# Fastest way to open and deal with a URL in a web browser in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Using `Selenium` package I am trying to open a `URL` in a browser. The browser can be `Firefox` or `Google`. Given `URL` is redirected to some other `URL` and the browser has to wait for this until its `URL` gets changed. Here's the code I'm using:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
starttime = time.time()
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='\\somepath\\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get("http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?patentnumber=3,930,293")
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 5)
wait.until(lambda driver: browser.current_url !=patent )
url = browser.current_url
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

for tag in soup.find_all(text=re.compile('Current U.S. Class:')):
    table = tag.findParent('table')
    result = table.find('tr').text
    browser.close()
    print(result)  # Current U.S. Class: 29/428 
    print(time.time() - starttime)
```

But this takes too much time (like 18 to 20 seconds) and I have a huge dataset of these URLs to work on. Is there any faster way to do this task?

Comment: Okay, it will be a new trick for me I 'll search for it but do you think it would help me out? I'll appreciate you if you provide any code example @OmarEinea

Comment: Sure, have your time I'll appreciate your efforts if you help me out with this. Thank you so much @OmarEinea

Comment: one thing though, are all urls from the same website?

Comment: yes all belong to the same "USPTO" website @OmarEinea

Comment: I simply have to change these `3,930,293` numbers in above-mentioned URL i.e http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?patentnumber=3,930,293 to access other URL's @OmarEinea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the response of the original URL, it only contains an HTML redirect to the new URL:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Single Document</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="1;URL=/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=3,930,293.PN.&OS=PN/3,930,293&RS=PN/3,930,293">
</HEAD>
</HTML>
```

Assuming response is always going to have the same format / content, you could easily capture the sub-URL from this response using RegEx, like so:

```
re.search('CONTENT="1;URL=(.+)"', r.text).group(1)
```

Then go to it. That all can be done by requests now, so you won't need to wait for Selenium!

---

Here's your code after using the trick above:

```
import time, requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
start_time = time.time()
root_url = "http://patft.uspto.gov"
r = requests.get(root_url + "/netacgi/nph-Parser?patentnumber=3,930,293")
r = requests.get(root_url + re.search('CONTENT="1;URL=(.+)"', r.text).group(1))

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

for tag in soup.find_all(string='Current U.S. Class:'):
    table = tag.findParent('table')
    result = table.find('tr').text
    print(result)
    print(time.time() - start_time)
```

Output:

```
Current U.S. Class: 29/428; 28/284; 28/297; 8/155 
2.2239434719085693
```

Comment: This code works fine for my machine but it gives an error on virtual machine fir some of urls. The error is Nonetype object has no attribute group. @Omar Einea